# Browser (Opera, Chromium...) start causing Permission denied (13) error for shared memory

Tags: arch-linux, browser, shared-memory

Using Manjaro / Arch linux, I wanted to install another browser. However, no matter whether I installed Opera or Chromium (via pacman) I always get an error when executing it (from both Application Launcher and shell).

Running **Chromium** it from the shell I get:

```
$ chromium                                                                                             
[11452:11452:0914/225931.419271:ERROR:platform_shared_memory_region_posix.cc(217)] Creating shared memory in /dev/shm/.org.chromium.Chromium.5FNz4h failed: Permission denied (13)
[11452:11452:0914/225931.419316:ERROR:platform_shared_memory_region_posix.cc(220)] Unable to access(W_OK|X_OK) /dev/shm: Permission denied (13)
[11452:11452:0914/225931.419320:FATAL:platform_shared_memory_region_posix.cc(222)] This is frequently caused by incorrect permissions on /dev/shm.  Try 'sudo chmod 1777 /dev/shm' to fix.
[0914/225931.424145:ERROR:elf_dynamic_array_reader.h(64)] tag not found
[0914/225931.424372:ERROR:elf_dynamic_array_reader.h(64)] tag not found
[0914/225931.424389:ERROR:elf_dynamic_array_reader.h(64)] tag not found
zsh: trace trap (core dumped)  chromium
```

Similar error for **Opera**:

```
$ opera                                                                                                
[11882:11882:0914/230407.927506:ERROR:platform_shared_memory_region_posix.cc(217)] Creating shared memory in /dev/shm/.org.chromium.Chromium.VS4HRD failed: Permission denied (13)
[11882:11882:0914/230407.927725:ERROR:platform_shared_memory_region_posix.cc(220)] Unable to access(W_OK|X_OK) /dev/shm: Permission denied (13)
[11882:11882:0914/230407.927735:FATAL:platform_shared_memory_region_posix.cc(222)] This is frequently caused by incorrect permissions on /dev/shm.  Try 'sudo chmod 1777 /dev/shm' to fix.
Discarded=1
zsh: illegal hardware instruction (core dumped)  opera
Discarded=1
```

The by default installed Firefox however is working fine (so no network issues or such kind). I could imagine it is a configuration / safety issue (like Apparmor etc.).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a reboot solved the issue.
However I have no idea what happened - and why it only seems to happen to browsers.